# Clear/Wipe Samsung with broken screen and Stock ROM

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-2, broken-screen

I have a broken Samsung Note II GT-N7100 and want to wipe it before dumping it. The point is: The Screen is broken and I can't see anything on the screen. I'm not sure whether USB debugging is turned on, so I guess it's not.
It's running some Stock 4.4 ROM and I can see it show up in the Windows Explorer. When I tried accessing it with ADB Shell, it was not possible.

I thought whether there might be an ability to see the screen mirrored when connected with adb on the PC, but have no idea whether such a feature exists.

Any Ideas how to get to wipe this ol'guys' memory?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Visit our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) – and follow up to e.g. [Securely wiping a phone with a broken screen](/q/68172/16575) / [How do I erase all the data on Galaxy S4 if the screen is broken?](/q/95880/16575)

Comment: Thanks. As it is really old and has no wifi connection saved, the play store option from link 2 doesn't work. I tried my best with ADB, but get no connection. I investigated a bit further and found 2 promising tools to try out once I get ADB running:
http://marian.schedenig.name/2014/07/03/remote-control-your-android-phone-through-adb/ and http://www.vysor.io/